# Implication of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Just an interesting question I saw online. :)

---

Is the following statement true or false?

$$\large \dfrac{ab}{c^2} + \dfrac{bc}{a^2} + \dfrac{ca}{b^2} = 3 \iff \dfrac{a + b}{c} + \dfrac{b + c}{a} + \dfrac{c + a}{b} \in \{-3; 6\}$$

$a + b + c \ne 0$

Edit: In case you don't know, $a, b, c$ can be negative numbers too.

Comment: Is here assumed to be $$a,b,c>0$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No. :) Thanks for your interest

Comment: I take it as a know because on the right-hand side there exists a $-3$ and a negative number cannot be formed by additions of positive numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the equality $\dfrac{ab}{c^2}+\dfrac{bc}{a^2}+\dfrac{ca}{b^2}=3$ implies that for $x=ab, y=bc, z=ca$:

$$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=0\leftrightarrow (x+y+z)((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2)=0$$.

This in turn implies that either $ab+bc+ca=0 \hspace{0.3cm}(1)$ or $a=b=c \hspace{0.3cm}(2)$.

- **Case (1):**

We easily find by applying (1) solved for $a+b, b+c, c+a $ respectively:

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{a+b}{c}=-\frac{ab}{c^2}\\
&\frac{c+b}{a}=-\frac{bc}{a^2}\\
&\frac{a+c}{b}=-\frac{ac}{b^2}
\end{align}
$$
 and we finally find that 
$$\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{c+b}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b}=-\frac{ab}{c^2}
-\frac{bc}{a^2}
-\frac{ac}{b^2}=-3$$

by the original equation.

- **Case(2):**
  when $a=b=c$ it's easy to see that

$$\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{c+b}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b}=6$$

That means that the values of the algebraic expression in question could be either -3 or 6 given the constraint above.

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b,c$ are all positive then we have by Am-Gm:

$$\dfrac{ab}{c^2} + \dfrac{bc}{a^2} + \dfrac{ca}{b^2} \geq  3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{ab}{c^2} \cdot \dfrac{bc}{a^2} \cdot \dfrac{ca}{b^2}} = 3$$

With eqaulity iff $ \dfrac{ab}{c^2} = \dfrac{bc}{a^2} = \dfrac{ca}{b^2}$ which is iff $a=b=c$ so the value of expression is $6$.

---

Now suppose not all are positive. Clearly not all numbers $a,b,c$ can be negative. Suppose $a$ is positive and $b$ negative.

Put $x=a/c$ and $y=b/c$, then we can rewrite starting equation like $$x^3y^3+x^3+y^3=3x^2y^2$$

If we put $m= xy<0$ and $k=x+y$ we get 
$$ m^3+k^3-3mk-3m^2=0\implies k=-m \;\;\;{\rm or} \;\;\;k^2-km+m^2=3m$$

We would like to know what is the value of $${(x+y)(xy+x+y+1)\over xy}-2$$
i.e. $$E:={k(m+k+1)\over m}-2$$

If $m=-k$ we get $E=-3$.

If $3m =k^2-km+m^2={k^2+m^2+(k-m)^2\over 2}\geq 0$, then $m\geq 0$ but this is a contradiction since $m<0$.

Comment: Can you explain how $x^3y^3+x^3+y^3=3x^2y^2$ came out?

Comment: Why would I do that? I spent some time to write this down and you give me no credit.